# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: All params match/are correct yet still it doesn't run

Tags: php, pdo

I've researched the error and read several other similar posts.  Unfortunately I can't seem to get mine working. The bind labels and values match what's required by the query. They contain acceptable characters. They are designated as INT where appropriate. (default is STR, yes?).

Asking for a fresh pair of eyes because I haven't found anything in other questions to work out what else I should try.

Here's the full code.

```
//declaring the variables 
$business_id = '1234';
$sales_channel_id = '2345';
$order_type='retail';
$real_or_testing = 'testing';
$sale_quote_appro = 'sale';
$next_function = 'sale';
$todays_date = '2023-08-30';
$current_MySQL_Timestamp = '2020-08-30 12:35:05';
$domain = 'my.domain.com';



// query to enter orderId to the db 
$q = "INSERT INTO eateries_order_ids ( business_id
                                     , sales_channel_id
                                     , order_type
                                     , real_or_testing
                                     , sale_quote_appro
                                     , next_function
                                     , date_of_order
                                     , where_sold
                                     , order_progress
                                     , record_created
                                     , record_created_by 
                                     )
                                     VALUES ( :businessId
                                            , :salesChannelId
                                            , :orderType
                                            , :realOrTesting
                                            , :saleQuoteAppro
                                            , :nextFunction
                                            , :todaysDate
                                            , :domain1 
                                            , :firstTimestamp
                                            , :secondTimestamp 
                                            , :domain2
                                            )
                                            on duplicate key
                                              update order_progress = :thirdTimestamp";
                             
                            


 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
 


// bind the parameters 
$stmt->bindParam(':businessId' , $business_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':salesChannelId' , $sales_channel_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':orderType' , $order_type );
$stmt->bindParam(':realOrTesting' , $real_or_testing );
$stmt->bindParam(':saleQuoteAppro' , $sale_quote_appro );
$stmt->bindParam(':nextFunction' , $next_function );
$stmt->bindParam(':todaysDate' , $todays_date );
$stmt->bindParam(':domain1' , $domain );
$stmt->bindParam(':firstTimestamp' , $current_MySQL_Timestamp );
$stmt->bindParam(':secondTimsestamp' , $current_MySQL_Timestamp );
$stmt->bindParam(':domain2' , $domain );
$stmt->bindParam(':thirdTimestamp' , $current_MySQL_Timestamp );


// check stmt is correct
//echo "<pre>stmt dump"; var_dump($stmt); echo "</pre>";
that outputs:
stmt dumpobject(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
["queryString"]=>
string(1546) "INSERT INTO eateries_order_ids ( business_id
                                      , sales_channel_id
                                      , order_type
                                      , real_or_testing
                                      , sale_quote_appro
                                      , next_function
                                      , date_of_order
                                      , where_sold
                                      , order_progress
                                      , record_created
                                      , record_created_by 
                                      )
                                      VALUES ( :businessId
                                             , :salesChannelId
                                             , :orderType
                                             , :realOrTesting
                                             , :saleQuoteAppro
                                             , :nextFunction
                                             , :todaysDate
                                             , :domain1 
                                             , :firstTimestamp
                                             , :secondTimestamp 
                                             , :domain2)
                                             on duplicate key
                                                update order_progress = :thirdTimestamp"
}

// dump the error msg
var_dump( $conn->errorInfo());
```

That dump produces the following

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Error Message

> [30-Aug-2023 09:03:10 America/Chicago] PHP Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/account/domain.com/php-queries/takeaways/input-takeawayOrder-to-db.php on line 195

Comment: either turn the emulation mode ON or don't use the same placeholder twice

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see where I have repeated the use of the same placeholder.  That's why it shows domain1 and domain 2, for example. (same principle with timestamp.

Comment: well it's a simple typo then. check every placeholder one by one.

Comment: Thank you. Embarrassing there was one typo yet, with that fixed and all others gone through, the issue prevails.

Comment: How about you show us ALL the error message just as it is shown to you

Comment: No longer am I seeing errors in the logs yet it still doesn't run.  I'll scratch my head more and may come back later.

Comment: As requested (thanks) [30-Aug-2023 09:03:10 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/account/domain.com/php-queries/takeaways/input-takeawayOrder-to-db.php on line 195

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't run"? What do rowCount() and lastInsertId return after insert?